# get 400 bad request for http post method (upload file) in Angular 7

Tags: angular7, form-data

I have something strange and I can not find the raison for that, I have two Angular applications, in the first one I can upload my file correcclty to the back-end and in the second I am using the same code and the same service to upload the file but I get the error 400 bad request and I do not know where to look to find the error?

document.html

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxFill>
<form #ajouterUnFichier=ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmitUnFichier(descFichier, fichier)"
    fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxFlexAlign="center center" fxFlex="40%">
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" matInput #descFichier id="descFichier" placeholder="Entrez le nom">
</mat-form-field>

<input type="file" id="fichier" (change)="choisirFichier($event)" #fichier
       accept=".csv, .xlsx, .pdf, .doc"
/>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!ajouterUnFichier.valid">
    Enregistrer
  </button>
  <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="accent">
    Annuler
  </button>
</div>
```

in document.ts

```
selectedFile: File = null;

choisirFichier(event) {
if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
  this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
 }
}
onSubmitUnFichier(descriptif: any, file: any) {
this.personneDocumentS.createFile(descriptif, this.selectedFile).subscribe(
  res => {
    if (res.status === 'error') {
      console.log('Error');
    } else {
      console.log('Sucess ************* ');
    }
  }
);
}
```

in document.service

```
createFile(desc: string, fichier: File) {
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', fichier);
fd.append('id_personne', '1');
fd.append('nom_document', 'fileName');
fd.append('descriptif', desc);
return this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost/silose/documents/add', fd);
}
```

In the first app everything going very well but for the second one I have:

```
zone.js:3243 POST http://localhost/silose/documents/add 400 (Bad Request)
```

if you have any idea where to look to find the problem

regards